# Nodejs - Export Excel not downloading excelfile

Tags: node.js, npm, nodes

```
  var nodeExcel = require('excel-export');
  var conf = {}
  conf.cols = [{
  caption: 'Sl.',
  type: 'number',
  width: 3
    }
  ];
  var arr = [];
  arr.push([1]);
  conf.rows = arr;
  var result = nodeExcel.execute(conf);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
  res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
   "Report.xlsx");
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end(result, 'binary');
```

I am using excel-export node package to download excel file in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me. Below code downloads the excel file in browser.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var nodeExcel = require('excel-export');
var conf = {}
conf.cols = [{
        caption: 'Sl.',
        type: 'number',
        width: 3
    }];
var arr = [];
arr.push([1]);
conf.rows = arr;

var result = nodeExcel.execute(conf);

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats');
    res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + 
    "Report.xlsx");
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(result, 'binary');
});
app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("listening port 3000");
});
```

Comment: When I am downloading file it show error message " Do you want to recover contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workbook click Yes. " and File is downloaded empty no content is getting printed on excel

Comment: Yes , Now I have added all data into workbook and used var excel = require('exceljs'); . Now I am able to add data into Excel sheet using exceljs package. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Issue which I was facing is that I was making ajax get request But when I changed the request from ajax to direct API hit then it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your "arr". I had the same problem and just check the datatypes and encoding.

Comment: Issue is already resolved , for excel export I was using ajax call when I convert it into window.location.href  issue resolved

Comment: Cool..! Good look.